# How many Ain ع, How many Lam ل and How many ye ي‎ in Sura Haqqah?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

How many Ain ع, How many Lam ل and How many Ye ي‎ in Sura Haqqah? My goal is to find name  علي‎, ʿAlī in Suratil Haqqah, and main goal is to find individual letters how many times did they repeat in this Sura.
For Example in Ayatul Qursi Ain ع repeated 7 times
Ayatul Qursi Lam ل repeated 25 times
Ayatul Qursi Ye ي repeated 17 times

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for our site. We are not a peer support! Check our [help] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu'alaykum,

I do not know why you would want this information, but I searched through the surah and apparently there are: 38 occurrences of "'ayn", 117 occurrences of "laam", 103 occurrences of "yaa".

Additionally, And although there is no occurrence of "'Alē", there are three occurrences "'Alā": عَلَىٰ.

I just used zekr to search through the surah; I do not know how accurate these results are.

Jazak'Allah Khayrun.